# Database Name as variabe part 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @deb  nvarchar(200)
set @deb='raw'

insert into table11
select * from @deb.dbo.table2
```

The above code is not working.
Is there any way to use server name as variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change a column, table, schema, or database reference in a SQL statement.  On the other hand, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @deb  nvarchar(200);
set @deb = 'raw';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = '
insert into table11
    select * from @deb.dbo.table2
';

set @sql  = replace(@sql, '@deb', @deb);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: It is working but  storing only one row.In table2  i have 152 records but randomly taking one row

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, Use Dynamic SQL

```
declare @deb  nvarchar(200)
set @deb='raw'

declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = 'insert into table11
select * from '+@deb+'.dbo.table2'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: executing successfully but no records fetching.

Comment: no record fetching? it is suppose to insert all records from `table2` into `table1`. Is it happening?

Comment: Sorry , only  one record fetching.

Comment: Really? and you have multiple records in table?

Comment: in table2  i have 152 records, when ever i execute script the same record inserting in table. Means at a time only one record fetching , that too same record.

Comment: that's highly impossible, unless you are missing on something. See if you are checking correct server name, destination table etc

Comment: It working.. Sorry to trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82705/discussion-between-neminath-and-pravin-deshmukh).